# Is it safe to use setTimeout function in angular?

Tags: angular, performance, settimeout

Can it cause performance issues even though timeout is equal to 0?

```
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'value', value + '.00');
    }, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly fine to do.

Comment: I'd say, if you use setTimeout() probably you're doing something wrong